# Finding a part of a text from symbol to symbol

Tags: php, text, symbols, strstr

For example I have the text.

```
$text = 'Hello dear friend, my name is Jacky.
I am 25 years old and @I am earning* $500 per month, but @I am going* to earn more';
```

I want to find all parts in text that starts from symbol "@" and ends with symbol "*".
In this example I want to have such variables:

```
$found[1] = 'I am earning';
$found[2] = 'I am going';
```

Who can help me with this? I use strstr(), but it is failing when there is more than one found part.

Comment: You oughtta get a fulfilling answer soon, but this is done with preg_match. I can't remember the exact syntax for regex hence the comment.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php

Comment: "Who can help me with this?". Stack Overflow is not a mentor recruitment venue. Please ask a _specific question_, showing us something that you've tried.

Comment: I'd suggest you show your code, so somebody can show you how to extend it to multiple matches. That way you'll learn more...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/@(.*?)\*/', $str, $matches);
$matches = $matches[1];
```

Or:

```
preg_match_all('/(?<=@).*?(?=\*)/', $text, $matches);
$matches = $matches[0];
```

Both result in `$matches` equalling:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I am earning
    [1] => I am going
)
```

Comment: You probably want to make those `@`/`*` to be assertions. He doesn't want them in the result.

Comment: $found = $matches[0]; echo $found; // results "array";

Comment: @pzztzz:  It's an array, you cannot simply `echo` it.

Comment: Tim Cooper how can I echo first and second ?

Comment: @pzztzz:  `echo $matches[0] , "<br />", $matches[1];`

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => I am earning
    [1] => I am going
)

Answer (score 1):

Use `preg_match_all()`.

```
$text = 'Hello dear friend, my name is Jacky. I am 25 years old and @I am earning* $500 per month, but @I am going* to earn more';
preg_match_all("/(?<=@).*?(?=\*)/", $text, $found);
```

The matches will be stored in `$found`.